# How to use Java Fest for applet automation?

Tags: java, swing, testing, applet, automated-tests

I am a part time programmer trying to automate a java applet. I googled a lot and came to conclusion that Java fest is the best option. It is almost two hours I am trying to figure out how to use it but unable to do. I am unable to understand how to install Java fest? I am using eclipse. So the project I created for automation, how I include fest in it? I already found http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Swing+Module+Documentation but it did not help much.

Kindly help me in this. Thank you.

(Prob solved : Instead of java swing, I downloaded java assert and seraching for the jar file foolishly.)